# PopulateManagedSchema during installation returns error 500

Tags: installation, habitat

**I am trying to clone habitat version on my machine but I am getting following issue, What can be the reason for this error?**

> Error requesting
>   http://sitename/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all

[image]
**One more screenshot when I am trying to access the site directly:**

[image]
**And here are the logs generated:**

[image]
[image]

**The solutions referred so far :**

1. Enabled ASP, ASP.net 3.5 and ASP.net 4.7
   https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/p/8927/19147#19147
2. Added application pool of site in computer management

Comment: After enabled ASP, ASP.net 3.5 and 4.7 did you try the installation again after uninstalling the website?

Comment: Do I need to uninstall the website as well?..I am just cleaning up the folders after trying installation each time.

Comment: With Sitecore 9+ it is not good to just cleaning up the folders, it would be good to run a uninstall PS script. My suggestion is to try after this

Answer (score 4):

I am getting the same issue while installing the `Sitecore 10.2 XM Developer Workstation (XM Scaled)` on new machine.

I have installed all the prerequisite but I was missing URL Rewrite Module in my new machine. After install [IIS URL Rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite#additionalDownloads), I have reinstall it again and its working for me.

Comment: Thanks for this, really saved my time. I was facing the same issue while installing 10.2 XM.